# Extracting nth field of string delimited by ":" stored in a SQL column

Tags: sql-server, string, split, substring, charindex

I have a SQL table with the two following columns:

```
FORMAT  Sample
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:233,0:233:99:0,120,1800
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/1:101,61:220:99:835,0,1859
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:172,0:172:99:0,120,1800
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/1:185,232:417:99:0|1:8029494_T_G:8670,0,6429
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL  0/0:367,0:367:99:0,120,1800
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/1:150,198:348:99:0|1:8029494_T_G:7930,0,5677
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/1:148,196:344:99:0|1:8029494_T_G:7876,0,5652
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0:148,0:344:99:0|1:8029494_T_G:7876,8334,14591
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  0/0:148,0:344:99:0|1:8029494_T_G:7876,8334,14591
```

The FORMAT column specifies the IDs for the fields that are given in the following column splitted by ":".

I would like to extract specific fields from the second column based on the ID/position from the FORMAT column, i.e. AD (2nd), DP (3rd) or GQ (4th).

I was able to extract the AD field with the following code:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Sample, CHARINDEX(':',Sample)+1, CHARINDEX(':',Sample,5)-5) FROM Table 1;
```

The problem is that I am not able to extract the fields DP or GQ, since the length of the different fields is not always the same one and I cannot specify which should be the starting position to search for the following ":" location.

I also tried to use the Split function from this website:

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=50648

The problem is that I do not know how to declare a column as a variable so that I can extract the required field for every single row of the table.

The desired output for the [Sample] column should look like this:

```
GT  AD  DP  GQ
0/0 233,0   233 99
0/1 101,61  220 99
0/0 172,0   172 99
0/0 216,0   216 99
0/0 216,0   216 99
0/1 185,232 417 99
0/0 367,0   367 99
0/1 150,198 348 99
0/1 148,196 344 99
0/0 148,0   344 99
0/0 148,0   344 99
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: `charindex()` is not a MySQL function.  My guess is that you are using SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a little XML as the parser

**Example**

```
Select A.Format
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select Pos2 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos3 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')))
                      ,Pos4 = ltrim(rtrim(xDim.value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(A.Format,':','§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as xDim) as A 
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Format                  Pos2    Pos3    Pos4
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL          AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  AD      DP      GQ
GT:AD:DP:GQ:PGT:PID:PL  AD      DP      GQ
```

**Or a Simple version**

```
Select A.Format
      ,Pos2 = Cast('<x>' + replace(Format,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos3 = Cast('<x>' + replace(Format,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos4 = Cast('<x>' + replace(Format,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
 From  YourTable A
```

**Or if Open to a UDF**

Take a peek at [TSQL/SQL Server - table function to parse/split delimited string to multiple/separate columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104428/tsql-sql-server-table-function-to-parse-split-delimited-string-to-multiple-sep/46104652#46104652)

> **EDIT - Update for Sample**

```
Select A.Format
      ,GT = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,AD = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,DP = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,GQ = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
 From  YourTable A
```

Comment: That works when applied to the column FORMAT. However if you apply it to the column Sample as this: ``Select Table1.[Sample]
      ,Pos1 = Cast('<x>' + replace([Sample],':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos2 = Cast('<x>' + replace([Sample],':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,Pos3 = Cast('<x>' + replace([Sample],':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
 From  Table1``, the results are completely weird and not consistent

Comment: @Yatrosin tested on Sample.  What is the delimiter used for sample

Comment: Exactly the same ":". I also tried the function, but I don't know how to apply it to an entire column. I generated the Split function and I used the following command ``Select * from [dbo].[Split](Table1.[Sample],':')``. Thanks

Comment: @Yatrosin You've got sample data ... great ... perhaps if you edit your question and supply the desired results.

Comment: @Yatrosin See EDIT / Upate

Comment: I have tried it again and I see which is the problem now. This code resorts the output alphanumerically starting with the first column (GT) and so on. I would like to keep the original order of the rows. Is it easy to fix?

Comment: Dear @John-Cappelletti. I have tried to keep the original order with the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Table1.[Sample]) function, but I haven't been able to fix it. I thought it was easier. Can you help me fix that? Thanks

Comment: @Yatrosin On a call, but I will take a second look in 20 min

Comment: @Yatrosin OK, I'm not clear what or where the Row Order comes into play here.

Comment: If I apply the formula as it is right now, I get the following output instead the desired one: ``GT AD DP GQ
0/0 148,0 344 99
0/0 148,0 344 99
0/0 172,0 172 99
0/0 216,0 216 99
0/0 216,0 216 99
0/0 233,0 233 99
0/0 367,0 367 99
0/1 101,61 220 99
0/1 148,196 344 99
0/1 150,198 348 99
0/1 185,232 417 99``

Comment: @Yatrosin OK I think I understand.  The parsing is working, but your results are not in the original sequence.   Due to parallelism there is no gtd of record order unless specified with an ORDER BY.  If your original data does not have a proper sequence such as Identity or DateTime stamp you may be out of luck.

Comment: Ok, I get it. Thank you anyway