# Apply filtering criteria to several SQL columns based on the values of temporary table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, filtering, calculated-columns

I have the following Input data:

```
Chr   Start     End       Ref   Alt   FORMAT           Sample_01                       Sample_02                     Sample_03                      row_id
1     1111111   1111112   AG    -     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/1:233,233:465:99:0,120,1800   0/0:117,0:117:99:0,120,1800   0/0:4,0:4:.:0,0,10             1
1     1111121   1111122   T     -     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/1:5,3:8:35:835,0,1859         0/1:85,35:158:99:345,0,1834   0/1:37,32:108:99:478,0,782     2
1     1111131   1111132   G     A     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/0:172,0:172:99:0,120,1800     0/1:20,10:30:15:0,120,1800    0/0:134,0:134:99:0,120,1800    3
1     1111141   1111142   A     G     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800     0/0:109,0:109:99:0,120,1800   0/1:135,10:145:99:0,120,1800   4
1     1111145   1111146   T     C     GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL   0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800     0/0:109,0:109:99:0,120,1800   0/1:5,75:80:75:0,120,1800      5
```

See following link to see how to get nth value of string field for Sample_01 ([Extracting nth field of string delimited by ":" stored in a SQL column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48100100/extracting-nth-field-of-string-delimited-by-stored-in-a-sql-column)).

I would like to get the following output table:

```
Chr   Start     End       Ref   Alt   FORMAT   Sample_01   Sample_02   Sample_03   row_id
1     1111111   1111112   AG    -     GT       0/1         0/0         ./.         1
1     1111121   1111122   T     -     GT       ./.         0/1         0/1         2
1     1111131   1111132   G     A     GT       0/0         ./.         0/0         3
1     1111141   1111142   A     G     GT       0/0         0/0         ./.         4
1     1111145   1111146   T     C     GT       0/0         0/0          ./.        5
```

This table takes into account the following criteria:

- All '.' values from DP column need to be converted into '0'
- All '.' values from GQ column need to be converted into '0'

The GTs need to be converted into './.' (missing) in three different scenarios:

- When DP is less than 15.
- When GQ is less than 20.
- When GT is '1/0' or GT is '0/1' AND the computed Ratio is <= 0.33 or the computed Ratio is >= 3. Ratio is computed as left part of AD / right part of AD.

Explanation of modified values:

- The GT in the first row of Sample_03 was modified because the GQ was originally '.' and this value was replaced by '0'.
- The GT in the second row of Sample_01 was modified because the DP was lower than 10.
- The GT in the third row of Sample_02 was modified because the GQ was lower than 30.
- The GT in the fourth and fifth rows of Sample_03 were modified because the Ratios for these two GTs were 13.5 and 0.0666, respectively.

I would like to use a function that can be applied to a table with a variable number of samples and I would like to specify which are the identifiers of the columns that contain Sample information so that the filtering criteria are applied to those columns only.

This is the code that I already have:

To generate temporary table for Sample_01:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_Sample_01(
[FORMAT] varchar (22),
row_id int,
GT nvarchar (5),
AD nvarchar (256),
DP nvarchar (256),
GQ nvarchar (256),
Ratio dec (6,3)
)

INSERT INTO #test_Sample_01 ([FORMAT], row_id, GT, AD, DP, GQ, Ratio)
SELECT Table1.[FORMAT], Table1.row_id
      ,GT = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
      ,AD = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
      ,DP = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
      ,GQ = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')
      ,CAST(LEFT(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),
       CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))-1) AS FLOAT) / 
       NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),
       CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))+1,5) AS FLOAT),0) AS Ratio
FROM  Table1
ORDER BY row_id
```

To clean this table:

```
UPDATE #test_Sample_01
SET DP = REPLACE(DP, '.', NULL)
WHERE DP LIKE '.'

UPDATE #test_Sample_01
SET GQ = REPLACE(GQ, '.', NULL)
WHERE GQ LIKE '.'


UPDATE #test_Sample_01
    SET GT = './.'
    WHERE (
        DP < 15 OR
        GQ < 20 OR
        ((GT = '1/0' OR GT = '0/1') AND
        (Ratio <= 0.33 OR Ratio >=3))
    )
```

To generate new table with cleaned data:

```
SELECT * 
INTO Table1_clean
FROM Table1

UPDATE Table1_clean
SET Table1_clean.Sample_01 = #test_Sample_01.GT
FROM Table1_clean INNER JOIN #test_Sample_01 
ON Table1_clean.row_id = #test_Sample_01.row_id
```

I just would like to apply this code to all "Sample" columns

Thank you very much,

Yatrosin

Comment: Can you clean out all the history of how you got here, and condense your question down to what single thing it is you need to do that you don't know how to do?

Comment: I have most of my code. I was told to reduce my question. I had everything explain there. I just don't know how to apply it to several columns at the same time. I can post it if you want

Comment: Dear @John-Cappelletti, can you have a look at this question? You helped me yesterday to figure out how to solve the first part of my problem. Thanks

Comment: This is a very elaborate question. +1 from my side

Comment: What does *I would like to use a function that can be applied to a table with a variable number of samples* mean? Might the table have more columns `Sample_04, Sample_05, etc`? That makes this design even worse... If so: Is there a known maximum?

Comment: Dear Shnugo, As you already guessed from my comment, the table can have up to 48 samples. That was the reason to ask for a function. The input is in this format, because this comes from a genetics sequencing format specification that has always this output format. It is not that I designed the table like this because I wanted and I thought it was a good design. In fact, I know each sample-row id should be in a different line, since the row ids can be really a lot of them (I am talking about thousand hundreds). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There might be better solutions than this one, but this is the best option I have found so far.

Generate the output table where you are going to export the clean data.

```
SELECT * 
INTO Table1_clean
FROM Table1
```

Generate a SELECT statement that prints the entire code for every single sample that needs to be processed.

```
SELECT
'CREATE TABLE #test_' + name + ' (
[FORMAT] varchar (22),
row_id int,
GT nvarchar (5),
AD nvarchar (256),
DP nvarchar (256),
GQ nvarchar (256),
Ratio dec (6,3)
)
INSERT INTO #test_' + name + '([FORMAT], row_id, GT, AD, DP, GQ, Ratio)
SELECT Table1.[FORMAT], Table1.row_id
      ,GT = Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[1]'',''varchar(max)'')
      ,AD = Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[2]'',''varchar(max)'')
      ,DP = Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[3]'',''varchar(max)'')
      ,GQ = Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[4]'',''varchar(max)'')
      ,CAST(LEFT(Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[2]'',''varchar(max)''),
       CHARINDEX('','', Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[2]'',''varchar(max)''))-1) AS FLOAT) / 
       NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[2]'',''varchar(max)''),
       CHARINDEX('','', Cast(''<x>'' + replace(' + name + ','':'',''</x><x>'')+''</x>'' as xml).value(''/x[2]'',''varchar(max)''))+1,5) AS FLOAT),0) AS Ratio
 FROM  Table1
 ORDER BY row_id

UPDATE #test_' + name + '
SET DP = REPLACE(DP, ''.'', NULL)
WHERE DP LIKE ''.''

UPDATE #test_' + name + '
SET GQ = REPLACE(GQ, ''.'', NULL)
WHERE GQ LIKE ''.''

 UPDATE #test_' + name + '
    SET GT = ''./.''
    WHERE (
        DP < 15 OR
        GQ < 20 OR
        ((GT = ''1/0'' OR GT = ''0/1'') AND
        (Ratio <= 0.33 OR Ratio >=3))
    )

SELECT * FROM Table1_clean
UPDATE South_Table1_clean
    SET Table1_clean.' + name + ' = #test_' + name + '.GT
    FROM Table1_clean INNER JOIN #test_' + name + ' 
    ON Table1_clean.row_id = #test_' + name + '.row_id'
FROM syscolumns
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'Table1')
AND name IN ('Sample_01', 'Sample_02', 'Sample_03')
```

This will generate these three statements automatically and they can be run once after another to get the filtered data printed to the Table1_clean table:

```
CREATE TABLE #test_Sample_01 (  [FORMAT] varchar (22),  row_id int,  GT nvarchar (5),  AD nvarchar (256),  DP nvarchar (256),  GQ nvarchar (256),  Ratio dec (6,3)  )  INSERT INTO #test_Sample_01([FORMAT], row_id, GT, AD, DP, GQ, Ratio)  SELECT South_American_panel.[FORMAT], South_American_panel.row_id        ,GT = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')        ,AD = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')        ,DP = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')        ,GQ = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')        ,CAST(LEFT(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))-1) AS FLOAT) /       NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_01,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))+1,5) AS FLOAT),0) AS Ratio   FROM  South_American_panel   ORDER BY row_id    UPDATE #test_Sample_01  SET DP = REPLACE(DP, '.', NULL)  WHERE DP LIKE '.'    UPDATE #test_Sample_01  SET GQ = REPLACE(GQ, '.', NULL)  WHERE GQ LIKE '.'     UPDATE #test_Sample_01   SET GT = './.'   WHERE (    DP < 15 OR    GQ < 20 OR    ((GT = '1/0' OR GT = '0/1') AND    (Ratio <= 0.33 OR Ratio >=3))   )    SELECT * FROM Table1_clean  UPDATE Table1_clean   SET Table1_clean.Sample_01 = #test_Sample_01.GT   FROM Table1_clean INNER JOIN #test_Sample_01    ON Table1_clean.row_id = #test_Sample_01.row_id

CREATE TABLE #test_Sample_02 (  [FORMAT] varchar (22),  row_id int,  GT nvarchar (5),  AD nvarchar (256),  DP nvarchar (256),  GQ nvarchar (256),  Ratio dec (6,3)  )  INSERT INTO #test_Sample_02([FORMAT], row_id, GT, AD, DP, GQ, Ratio)  SELECT South_American_panel.[FORMAT], South_American_panel.row_id        ,GT = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')        ,AD = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')        ,DP = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')        ,GQ = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')        ,CAST(LEFT(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))-1) AS FLOAT) /       NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_02,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))+1,5) AS FLOAT),0) AS Ratio   FROM  South_American_panel   ORDER BY row_id    UPDATE #test_Sample_02  SET DP = REPLACE(DP, '.', NULL)  WHERE DP LIKE '.'    UPDATE #test_Sample_02  SET GQ = REPLACE(GQ, '.', NULL)  WHERE GQ LIKE '.'     UPDATE #test_Sample_02   SET GT = './.'   WHERE (    DP < 15 OR    GQ < 20 OR    ((GT = '1/0' OR GT = '0/1') AND    (Ratio <= 0.33 OR Ratio >=3))   )    SELECT * FROM Table1_clean  UPDATE Table1_clean   SET Table1_clean.Sample_02 = #test_Sample_02.GT   FROM Table1_clean INNER JOIN #test_Sample_02    ON Table1_clean.row_id = #test_Sample_02.row_id

CREATE TABLE #test_Sample_03 (  [FORMAT] varchar (22),  row_id int,  GT nvarchar (5),  AD nvarchar (256),  DP nvarchar (256),  GQ nvarchar (256),  Ratio dec (6,3)  )  INSERT INTO #test_Sample_03([FORMAT], row_id, GT, AD, DP, GQ, Ratio)  SELECT South_American_panel.[FORMAT], South_American_panel.row_id        ,GT = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')        ,AD = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')        ,DP = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')        ,GQ = Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[4]','varchar(max)')        ,CAST(LEFT(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))-1) AS FLOAT) /       NULLIF(CAST(SUBSTRING(Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'),      CHARINDEX(',', Cast('<x>' + replace(Sample_03,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).value('/x[2]','varchar(max)'))+1,5) AS FLOAT),0) AS Ratio   FROM  South_American_panel   ORDER BY row_id    UPDATE #test_Sample_03  SET DP = REPLACE(DP, '.', NULL)  WHERE DP LIKE '.'    UPDATE #test_Sample_03  SET GQ = REPLACE(GQ, '.', NULL)  WHERE GQ LIKE '.'     UPDATE #test_Sample_03   SET GT = './.'   WHERE (    DP < 15 OR    GQ < 20 OR    ((GT = '1/0' OR GT = '0/1') AND    (Ratio <= 0.33 OR Ratio >=3))   )    SELECT * FROM Table1_clean  UPDATE Table1_clean   SET Table1_clean.Sample_03 = #test_Sample_03.GT   FROM Table1_clean INNER JOIN #test_Sample_03    ON Table1_clean.row_id = #test_Sample_03.row_id
```

I would appreciate if someone explains a more elegant way of solving this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Do I have to tell you, that this is a very bad design? If you can change this you really should... Any approach will be slow, erronous and hard to maintain.

If you have to stick with this, you might try this:

btw:

> I would like to use a function

In this case you cannot go with generated SQL or temp tables. My approach is fully inlined single statement, even working in iTVF.

```
DECLARE @YourTbl TABLE(Chr INT,Start INT,[End] INT,Ref VARCHAR(100),Alt VARCHAR(100),[FORMAT] VARCHAR(100),Sample_01 VARCHAR(100),Sample_02 VARCHAR(100),Sample_03 VARCHAR(100),row_id INT);
INSERT INTO @YourTbl VALUES 
 (1,1111111,1111112,'AG','-','GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL','0/1:233,233:465:99:0,120,1800','0/0:117,0:117:99:0,120,1800','0/0:4,0:4:.:0,0,10',1)
,(1,1111121,1111122,'T','-','GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL','0/1:5,3:8:35:835,0,1859','0/1:85,35:158:99:345,0,1834','0/1:37,32:108:99:478,0,782',2)
,(1,1111131,1111132,'G','A','GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL','0/0:172,0:172:99:0,120,1800','0/1:20,10:30:15:0,120,1800','0/0:134,0:134:99:0,120,1800',3)
,(1,1111141,1111142,'A','G','GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL','0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800','0/0:109,0:109:99:0,120,1800','0/1:135,10:145:99:0,120,1800',4)
,(1,1111145,1111146,'T','C','GT:AD:DP:GQ:PL','0/0:216,0:216:99:0,120,1800','0/0:109,0:109:99:0,120,1800','0/1:5,75:80:75:0,120,1800',5);

WITH SemiNormalised AS
(
    SELECT up.Chr,up.Start,up.[End],up.Ref,up.Alt
          ,up.row_id
          ,up.SampleName 
          ,A.Casted.value('/x[1]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS GT
          ,B.AD_xml.value('/y[1]/text()[1]','float') AS AD1
          ,B.AD_xml.value('/y[2]/text()[1]','float') AS AD2
          ,ISNULL(A.Casted.value('/x[3]/text()[1] cast as xs:float?','float'),0.0) AS DP --will implicitly cast a numeric value to a float, otherwise 0.0 
          ,ISNULL(A.Casted.value('/x[4]/text()[1] cast as xs:float?','float'),0.0) AS GQ --will implicitly cast a numeric value to a float, otherwise 0.0 
          ,A.Casted.value('/x[5]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)') AS PL
    FROM
     (
      SELECT * FROM @YourTbl
     ) AS t
     UNPIVOT
     (
        SampleData FOR SampleName IN (Sample_01,Sample_02,Sample_03 /*add more if needed*/) 
     ) AS up
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT Cast('<x>' + replace(SampleData,':','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) AS Casted) AS A
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<y>' + REPLACE(A.Casted.value('/x[2]/text()[1]','nvarchar(10)'),',','</y><y>') + '</y>' AS XML) AS AD_xml) AS B
)
,BusinessRules AS
(
    SELECT Chr,Start,[End],Ref,Alt
          ,row_id
          ,SampleName 
          ,CASE WHEN DP<15 OR GQ<20 THEN './.' 
                ELSE CASE WHEN (GT='1/0' OR GT='0/1') AND (A.Ratio <= 0.33 OR A.Ratio>= 3) THEN './.' ELSE GT END --dont understand this really...
                END AS GT
          ,AD1
          ,AD2
          ,A.Ratio
          ,DP
          ,GQ
          ,PL
    FROM SemiNormalised
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT AD1/NULLIF(AD2,0) AS Ratio) AS A --NULLIF will avoid division by 0
)
SELECT p.*
FROM
(
    SELECT Chr,Start,[End],Ref,Alt
          ,row_id
          ,SampleName
          ,GT
    FROM BusinessRules 
) AS t
PIVOT
(
    MAX(GT) FOR SampleName IN(Sample_01,Sample_02,Sample_03 /*add more if needed*/) 
) AS p
```

Check the intermediate output

```
SELECT * FROM SemiNormalised
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| Chr | Start   | End     | Ref | Alt | row_id | SampleName | GT  | AD1 | AD2 | DP  | GQ | PL         |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_01  | 0/1 | 233 | 233 | 465 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 117 | 0   | 117 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_03  | 0/0 | 4   | 0   | 4   | 0  | 0,0,10     |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_01  | 0/1 | 5   | 3   | 8   | 35 | 835,0,1859 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_02  | 0/1 | 85  | 35  | 158 | 99 | 345,0,1834 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_03  | 0/1 | 37  | 32  | 108 | 99 | 478,0,782  |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 172 | 0   | 172 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_02  | 0/1 | 20  | 10  | 30  | 15 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_03  | 0/0 | 134 | 0   | 134 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 216 | 0   | 216 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 109 | 0   | 109 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_03  | 0/1 | 135 | 10  | 145 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 216 | 0   | 216 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 109 | 0   | 109 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_03  | 0/1 | 5   | 75  | 80  | 75 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+----+------------+
```

Second intermediate output

```
SELECT * FROM BusinessRules 
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| Chr | Start   | End     | Ref | Alt | row_id | SampleName | GT  | AD1 | AD2 | Ratio              | DP  | GQ | PL         |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_01  | 0/1 | 233 | 233 | 1                  | 465 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 117 | 0   | NULL               | 117 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | Sample_03  | ./. | 4   | 0   | NULL               | 4   | 0  | 0,0,10     |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_01  | ./. | 5   | 3   | 1,66666666666667   | 8   | 35 | 835,0,1859 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_02  | 0/1 | 85  | 35  | 2,42857142857143   | 158 | 99 | 345,0,1834 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | Sample_03  | 0/1 | 37  | 32  | 1,15625            | 108 | 99 | 478,0,782  |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 172 | 0   | NULL               | 172 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_02  | ./. | 20  | 10  | 2                  | 30  | 15 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | Sample_03  | 0/0 | 134 | 0   | NULL               | 134 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 216 | 0   | NULL               | 216 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 109 | 0   | NULL               | 109 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | Sample_03  | ./. | 135 | 10  | 13,5               | 145 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_01  | 0/0 | 216 | 0   | NULL               | 216 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_02  | 0/0 | 109 | 0   | NULL               | 109 | 99 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | Sample_03  | ./. | 5   | 75  | 0,0666666666666667 | 80  | 75 | 0,120,1800 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+------------+-----+-----+-----+--------------------+-----+----+------------+
```

Final output

```
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Chr | Start   | End     | Ref | Alt | row_id | Sample_01 | Sample_02 | Sample_03 |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1111111 | 1111112 | AG  | -   | 1      | 0/1       | 0/0       | ./.       |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1111121 | 1111122 | T   | -   | 2      | ./.       | 0/1       | 0/1       |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1111131 | 1111132 | G   | A   | 3      | 0/0       | ./.       | 0/0       |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1111141 | 1111142 | A   | G   | 4      | 0/0       | 0/0       | ./.       |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1   | 1111145 | 1111146 | T   | C   | 5      | 0/0       | 0/0       | ./.       |
+-----+---------+---------+-----+-----+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```